# Problem obtaining eps file using TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio

The eps file generated using grace gets converted to blank pdf while other eps files are working well. I have attached the eps. I need to know what package is missing or what is the problem. I am using TeXStudio in windows.

The file is available at
https://www.filemail.com/d/itnnzjuofasmfbl

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: (1) Yuo should provide a full but minimal example such that we can see which packages etc you are using. (2) exactly which LaTeX installation are you using (3) can you provide a compilation log of that exact example. I have no issue manually converting your EPS to PDF on the command line